# How can I change menu font with custom font?

Tags: magento2, theme, custom

How can I change menu font with a custom font? 
The font is already installed in my child theme and I can use it on home page with

```
<style>font-family: 'BPG Arial Caps'; </style>
```

But how can I use it , parent theme is sm bestshop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set font for menu items using the css selector like below.

```
.navigation{
    .ui-menu{
        li{
            a{
                font-family: 'BPG Arial Caps';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try this code in you child theme css file.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you, oh, I feel good that I have improved when I check my question which I wrote 1 year ago...